# Pass Case Argument to Sub - VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm working on automating some excel tasks at work using VBA and having trouble with the following:

I'm trying to create a Sub with multiple Cases which I call with the Case as an argument but it's not working. It always selects the first case. Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?

Example:

Main Sub:

```
Public Sub Test()

Call CaseTest(Case2)

End Sub
```

"Called Sub":

```
Public Sub CaseTest(CaseSelect)

Select Case CaseSelect

Case Case1

MsgBox "Case1"

Case Case2

MsgBox "Case2"

End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `Case1` and `Case2` are treated as variables. I'd recommend you to add `Option Explicit` statement as a first line of each your module - this will detect such errors printing "Undefined variable" error message.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it describes a beginner coding error without general interest for our readers.

Comment: @Akina I have read that so many times and still haven't learned, maybe now I will as I wasted quite a bit of time on this issue.

Comment: [Why was my question closed? Is VBA on Topic for SuperUser](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13724/116475)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When testing Case against strings that Case statement needs Quotes as well as the argument.

Eg:

Main Sub:

```
Public Sub Test()

Call CaseTest("Case2") ' Note the ""

End Sub
```

"Called Sub":

```
Public Sub CaseTest(CaseSelect)

Select Case CaseSelect

Case "Case1"

MsgBox "Case1"

Case "Case2" ' Note the ""

MsgBox "Case2"

End Select
End Sub
```